# Lipipq(iptables) . How do I redirect captured packet to another address with iptables queue?

Tags: c, queue, iptables, billing

I don't know how to solve my problem.

Is it possible to redirect captured packet with ipq_set_verdict()?

I want to redirect unauthorized users to login page.

Please see my code:

The packets are accepted and my browser opens requested page(not changed destination address)

void main() {
    struct ipq_handle* h;

```
if (!(h = ipq_create_handle(0, PF_INET))) {
    //error 
    return;
};

if ((ipq_set_mode(h, IPQ_COPY_PACKET, BUFSIZE)) < 0) {
    // error 
    return;
};


struct iphdr* ip_pack;
ipq_packet_msg_t* eth_pack;

__u32 ip_auth_server = inet_addr("192.168.177.1");
unsigned char buf[68000];

if ((ipq_read(h, buf, BUFSIZE, 0)) < 0) {

    //error
    return;

}


switch (ipq_message_type(buf)) {
    case NLMSG_ERROR:
        //error
        break;

    case IPQM_PACKET:
    {

        eth_pack = ipq_get_packet(buf);
        ip_pack = (struct iphdr*) eth_pack->payload;
        redirect_server_auth(ip_auth_server, ip_pack, eth_pack->packet_id, h, eth_pack->payload, eth_pack->data_len);

    }


}

u_int16_t ip_checksum(u_int32_t init, const u_int8_t* buf, size_t len) {
    u_int32_t sum = init;
    u_int16_t* shorts = (u_int16_t*) buf;

    while (len > 1) {
        sum += *shorts++;
        len -= 2;
    }

    if (len == 1)
        sum += *((u_int8_t*) shorts);

    while (sum >> 16)
        sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xFFFF);

    return ~sum;
}

u_int16_t tcp_checksum(const struct iphdr* iph, const struct tcphdr* tcph,
        size_t len) {
    u_int32_t cksum = 0;

    cksum += (iph->saddr >> 16) & 0x0000ffff;
    cksum += iph->saddr & 0x0000ffff;
    cksum += (iph->daddr >> 16) & 0x0000ffff;
    cksum += iph->daddr & 0x0000ffff;
    cksum += htons(iph->protocol & 0x00ff);
    cksum += htons(len);
    return ip_checksum(cksum, (unsigned char*) tcph, len);
}

void handle_packet(unsigned char* pkt, size_t len, __u32 dest_addr, int port_dest) {
    struct iphdr* iph = (struct iphdr*) pkt;
    struct tcphdr* tcph = (struct tcphdr*) (pkt + iph->ihl * 4);


    iph->daddr = dest_addr;
    //      syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "PORT");
    //syslog(LOG_DEBUG, tcph->dest); //tcph->dest = htons(80);

    iph->check = 0;
    iph->check = ip_checksum(0, pkt, iph->ihl * 4);
    tcph->check = 0;
    tcph->check = tcp_checksum(iph, tcph, len - (iph->ihl * 4));

}

void redirect_server_auth(__u32* ip_srv, struct iphdr* ip_pack,
        unsigned long packet_id, ipq_handle* handle,
        unsigned char* buf, int size_buf) {

    syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "RENAME IP AND SEND PACK ACCEPT %s", inet_ntoa(
            *((struct in_addr*) & ip_pack->daddr)));


    handle_packet(buf, size_buf, *ip_srv, 80);


    syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "RENAME IP AND SEND PACK ACCEPT %s", inet_ntoa(

            *((struct in_addr*) & ip_pack->daddr)));

    int v = ipq_set_verdict(handle, packet_id, NF_ACCEPT, size_buf, buf);

    if (v < 0) {
        syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "problems");
        syslog(LOG_DEBUG, ipq_errstr());
    }

}
```

I'm looking forward your help. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

First, libipq is considered as deprecated, use libnefilter_queue instead.

Then it's not possible to redirect a packet with set_verdict, from what I got you can only use DROP ACCEPT or REJECT verdicts. But you can modify data payload/headers using [nfq_set_verdict2()](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/group__Queue.html#ga3bc913f9c84ae97b71055e4990834bdd). That seems to be what you are already doing.

I'm not 100% sure of what you want to do : redirect the browser to another (login) webpage if it is not authenticated ?

If so you should issue a 301 HTTP answer containing the authentication location instead of modifying the packet destination. And in this case, you should do that at application layer.

But still I'm not sure about what you actualy want do do, can you be more accurate about your system (how and who authenticates ? when ? and how do you check if the client is already authenticated ?)